# Passing object to method that will must have one specific property

Tags: typescript

I have a utility method like this:

```
function testUtil(row) {
    ...
    const i = row.Index;
    ...
}
```

How to set the type of 'row' anything but it must have Index property.

Comment: Can you have an unlimited number of other keys and values? Or do you have a specific where other keys are optional, except this one?

Comment: row could be any thing with any number of params. I just want to make sure whatever is passed it should have atleast one property i.e. Index

Comment: Do you still want to be able to access the other properties?

Comment: No..............

Comment: In that case, [Kenny Perroni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005792/) is what you need - you can pass any object as long as it has an `index` property of type `number`. If you try to get any other properties, the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an interface and make the row of that type.

```
interface IRowType {
 index: number;
}

function testUtilRow(row: IRowType){
  const index = row.index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Row {
    Index: number | string;
    [key: string]: any;
}
function testUtil(row: Row) {
    const i = row.Index;
}
```

This will allow `row` to have other keys but it must always have `Index`.